# AutoCAD. ActiveX Server возвратил ошибку: неизвестное имя: EffectiveName

Tags: lisp, activex, autocad

Пытаюсь использовать код взятый здесь http://forum.dwg.ru/showpost.php?p=1099760&postcount=6
Наткнулся на странное поведение. Если в файле есть автокадовская таблица, то появляется ошибка "неизвестное имя: EffectiveName". Если таблицу удалить, то всё работает замечательно.
Подскажите почему так и как можно это исправить.
Windows 8 64x. AutoCAD 2015 SP2

```
 (defun AnonymousInstancesof ( block / def rec nme ref lst )
;; Returns list of the Anonymous names taken by a Dynamic Block (if any)  -  Lee Mac 2011  -  www.lee-mac.com
;; edit VVA 2013.10.16
;; Arguments:  block  - name of Dynamic Block.
;; http://www.cadtutor.net/forum/showthread.php?56447-Automatically-filling-out-the-Drawing-Property-from-Titleblock-Information&p=382978&viewfull=1#post382978
;; http://forum.dwg.ru/showthread.php?t=99353  
  (while (setq def (tblnext "BLOCK" (null def)))
    (if (= 1 (logand 1 (cdr (assoc 70 def))))
      (progn
        (setq rec
          (entget
            (cdr
              (assoc 330
                (entget
                  (tblobjname "BLOCK" (setq nme (cdr (assoc 2 def))))
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
        (while (setq ref (assoc 331 rec))
          (if
            (and
              (cdr ref) ;;;Add VVA 2013-10-16
              (entget (cdr ref)) ;;;Add VVA 2013-10-16
              (eq block (vla-get-effectivename (vlax-ename->vla-object (cdr ref))))
              (not (member nme lst))
            )
            (setq lst (cons nme lst))
          )
          (setq rec (cdr (member (assoc 331 rec) rec)))
        )
      )
    )
  )
  (reverse lst)
)

(print (AnonymousInstancesof "blockname"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Помогла добавка такой проверки:

```
(vlax-property-available-p (vlax-ename->vla-object (cdr ref)) 'effectivename)
```